# How Do I make an Acer T230H Touchcreen work on Ubuntu 9.10?

Tags: ubuntu, touchscreen

I've done this so far:

```
sudo nano /etc/udev/rules.d/99-touchscreen.rules
```

And added:

```
SUBSYSTEM=="usb", ATTRS{idVendor}=="0408", ATTRS{idProduct}=="3000", SYMLINK+="usb/quanta_touch"
SUBSYSTEM=="input", KERNEL=="event*", ATTRS{idVendor}=="0408", ATTRS{idProduct}=="3000", SYMLINK+="input/quanta_touch"
```

```
sudo service udev restart
```

then the instructions here:
http://ubuntuforums.org/showpost.php?p=8932808&postcount=36

And then added to my xorg conf:

```
Section "InputDevice"
 Identifier      "Acer T230H"
 Driver          "hidtouch"
 Option          "SendCoreEvents"        "true"
 Option          "ReportingMode"         "Raw"
 Option          "Device"                "/dev/usb/quanta_touch"
 Option          "PacketCount"           "13"
 Option          "OpcodePressure"        "852034"
 Option          "OpcodeX"               "65584"
 Option          "OpcodeY"               "65585"
 Option          "CalibrationModel"      "1"
 Option          "CornerTopLeftX"        "0"
 Option          "CornerTopLeftY"        "0"
 Option          "CornerTopRightX"       "1920" # 1920 for 23"
 Option          "CornerTopRightY"       "0"
 Option          "CornerBottomLeftX"     "0"
 Option          "CornerBottomLeftY"     "1080"  # 1080 for 23"
 Option          "CornerBottomRightX"    "1920" # 1920 for 23"
 Option          "CornerBottomRightY"    "1080"  # 1080 for 23"
 Option          "CornerScreenWidth"     "1920" # 1920 for 23"
 Option          "CornerScreenHeight"    "1080"  # 1080 for 23"
EndSection

Section "ServerLayout"
    Identifier "Touchscreen"
    InputDevice "Acer T230H" "SendCoreEvents"
EndSection
```

And restarted. And the touchscreen does nothing. Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well it works under 10.04, and 10.04.01 fixed the issue with 10.04 OS being slow. Since 10.04.01 runs at a decent speed, I think that's the current "best answer".